# How show external html header in Salesforce community/experience

Tags: community, experience-cloud, community-cloud, salesforce-cms

I have to replace community header with AEM header(external html site) and based on dynamic AEM site header URL. CMS Connect does not support dynamic URL. We can only provide a fix header in CMS Connect. Is there any possible way to implement this requirement?
header url -> [www.xyz.com/en-sn/customer/header.html](http://www.xyz.com/en-sn/customer/header.html). here 'en-sn' and 'customer' is dynamic value which will populate based on community page parameters on page load.

Comment: Custom code the header. AEM provides lots of options for embedding content into 3rd party apps (SF without CMS Connect)

Comment: @identigral If I fetch all AEM Site's header data like html, js ,css in javascript code of aura/lwc. Will it work?